# download music from youtube with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, urllib2, urllib

i am trying to download songs from youtube as a mp3 files with python code, i tried many codes but none of them is working (there is a file named "a" in my project folder that downloaded but when i tried to play the song in the media player its not working), if someone knows what the problem, or has another code that can help me it will be very helpful. tnx

This is my code:

```
import urllib

url = "https://www.youtube.com/......"     

download = urllib.urlretrieve(url, "a.mp3")

download
```

Comment: i think you went a bit too far with the assumption that *Python can do magic*.

Comment: maybe your speaker is not connected

Comment: @AriGold its not a problem with the speaker, i checked it already...

Comment: hope that can help you, https://advencode.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/python-code-to-strip-audio-from-youtube-video/................you need ffmpeg also

Answer (score 4):

You can use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl), it is written in Python so you can import it from your code, here's a snippet from the [readme](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#embedding-youtube-dl):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

You can then set `ydl_opts = {'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio','preferredcodec': 'mp3','preferredquality': '192'}]}` to download in mp3 format with the given quality.

Comment: amazing lib!! out of box

Answer (score 0):

You can could [call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) from your code. Use --id to restrict only ID of the video as the file name.

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --id <link to video>
```

Then, you can access your audio file as ID.mp3 from the code.

Example:

```
audioFile = 'Tj75Arhq5ho.mp3'
command = 'youtube-dl --extract-audio --id https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj75Arhq5ho'
subprocess.call(command.split(), shell=False)
# ... do whatever you want with the audioFile here
```

Comment: why you wrote t.split()? i didn't understand what you meant

Comment: Sorry, it was mistake :)